# Dose calculation of X-Ray tubes

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, x-rays

I am working on a X ray tube project and I want to calculate approximate dose. Do you know any equation ?

I have found one on internet but I think this is wrong:

$$D=g\cdot kV^2\cdot \dfrac{mAs}{d^2}= \left[\dfrac{Sv}{h}\right]$$

So here is $g$-factor a constant and how can I find it (I mean if it is what is it for this equation, if it is not then how can I calculate it, because as well as I know $~g~$-factor depends on the angle of the anode and these things). And here the $~d^2~$ stands for distance but this the distance of what ? The distance between the tube and the object or the distance between cathode (filament) and anode (tungsten) ?

And can I calculate $~mAs (I\cdot t)~$ by $~\dfrac{kV}{R}~$ of the filament ?

Comment: Proportional to voltage squared? What is your source? (Not the x-ray source, I mean where did you get this from?)

Comment: I am trying to understand the expression. I suppose "mA" means milliamps? And "k" is not some constant but also a prefix, so the voltage in kilovolt? Units do not seem to match: the left hand side multiplies by time (in seconds), the right hand side has a dose rate in Sv/h? No, the current of a vacuum tube does not follow Ohm's law.

Comment: @Pieter I found it on researchgate.net, but it seemed me wrong so I wanted to verify it. mAs is miliampere second and kV is kilovolt yes. Do you know any other equation for my purpose sir ?

Comment: @nmasanta It's great that you've converted the formulae to MathJax, but I think you may have changed the meaning slightly. It's hard to tell because the OP hasn't responded to Pieter's requests for clarification. But I think $m$ is supposed to be the milli- prefix, not a separate quantity (eg mass). Also, $mAs (I\cdot t)$ is (probably) supposed to be 2 separate expressions, with the $(I\cdot t)$ being a synonym or explanation of $mAs$. Ah, fissile_uranium just responded as I was writing this comment. ;)

Comment: @fissile_uranium Can you give us a link for the source of that expression from researchgate.net?

Comment: Yes sir :) https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_calculate_X_ray_dose_using_mAs_and_kV_without_using_any_detector this and https://www.researchgate.net/post/The_formula_for_radiation_dose_of_an_x-ray_unit_D_gkVmAs_d2_where_g_is_constant_and_ddistance_in_what_kind_of_dose_does_it_refer_to this one. They are both including the same equation so I believed it's true :/

Comment: @PM2Ring do you hav any idea or knowledge about especially the g-factor sir ?

Comment: I expect that $d$ is the distance from the anode to the target area (the thing being x-rayed). $g$ is just a constant of proportionality that depends on the details of the tube's construction, you probably need to determine it empirically.

Comment: @PM2Ring but well I am building it by my own. How can I make the g constant the biggest or how can I determine it after building it ? Sorry I'm asking too much questions :/

Comment: FYI, _[dose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbed_dose)_ is something that happens in the target. The main quantity that you measure or predict for the tube is _[flux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux)_.

Comment: You can use the dose meter . fix distance , setting difference kV make exposure and write down the dose you have . then put into excel sheet . then create a curve.
from that curve you will got the formula .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be some engineering-type formula. From a different questions site, and it is difficult to make sense of.

X-ray flux is proportional to current $I$ (which is normally of the order of milli-ampères for x-ray tubes) and inversely proportional to $d^2$ when the distance $d$ is large compared to source size. Dose is also proportional to time $t$ (which can be measured in seconds or hours - unclear what here).

Electrical power is $P = IV$ and when voltage is in kV and the current in milliamps you get the product in watt.

Only a very small part of this power is emitted as x-rays. That fraction is increasing with voltage. A proportional increase would result in that $V^2$ factor, but there is no theoretical justification for proportionality.

So the $g$ in this parametrisation will depend on lots of things: anode material, for example. And angle. And on voltage.

If the left-hand side includes a multiplication with time to compute a time-integrated flux, you would need to multiply with the area of the target to get an absorbed dose. The unit for that is sievert. Dose *rate* can be expressed in Sv/h, but then you must not multiply with time on the left-hand side.